# Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element at Object.Hr [as render]

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha

I have a form with recaptcha that's displayed twice on the same page. Once on page load and possibly once again when if a modal is clicked.

The problem is when the form has to be rendered again I get the following error:

```
Error: reCAPTCHA has already been rendered in this element
       at Object.Hr [as render]
```

My code using [react-recaptcha](https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha):

```
form component:
...
    <Button
      onClick={this.executeCaptcha} 
      disabled={this.isFromValid() ? false : true}
    >
      Submit
    </Button>
    <Recaptcha
      ref={e => recaptchaInstance = e}
      sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      size="invisible"
      render="explicit"
      verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}
      onloadCallback={this.captchaCallback}
    />
  </div>

index.html:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

How can I solve this?